# write a list to CSV file and start new column if condition is met

Tags: python, csv

I have a list with data points and 'identifiers' that looks like this:

```
['identifier', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'identifier', 10, 11, 12, 13, 'identifier', ...]
```

I would like to write this list to a CSV file and start a new column for each identifier.
e.g.

```
 for data in list:
        if data=='identifier':
            ==> create a new column in the CSV file and print the subsequent data points
```

I'm looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Cheers,

-Sebastian

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing your attempts. There's thousands of existing questions about reading/writing CSVs on this site already. What have you tried from your research?

Comment: Hi, I have tried most of them. The element I am missing is to tell the writer to start a new column if a criteria is met.

Comment: Please include your best attempt as an edit to the question. It's far more useful to you if we could also address your misconceptions while answering the question

Comment: you might also think about why one "identifier" is followed by 4 values and why they shoudl go into new columns - you never talk about rows...

Comment: So you tried the "write file self" approach, the csv module aproach, used pandas to write it, used numpy to write it ... an nothing worked?

Comment: Is your data always identifier + numeric values. Could it be `['identifier', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'identifier', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'identifier', ...]`?  If so, how do you do you know the correct identifier tags?

Comment: Maybe you mean `rows` and not `columns`?

Comment: @pault yes you can. The `writerows` method takes a nested list, each inner list representing a row (each item in that list being in a separate column). You could easily break this input down into rows and columns as a nested list with `for` loops and probably compress that down into list comprehensions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post what you think the `.csv` file should look like. Such files generally have a fixed number of columns but it seems to me you want an output file with a variable number of columns. But I don't really understand what you want. Is `'identifier'` a literal value in your file, or is it a symbolic placeholder for `myidentifer1`, `myidentifer2` etc? Are there always 4 values? Why do you want to add one extra column if there are 4 extra values? Explain and exemplify, please.

Comment: @Sebastian.. Welcome to SO... fetch your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313605/creating-a-new-column-in-a-csv-file-from-a-list) and finish the tour. Tip: start using dictionaries.

Comment: @PatrickArtner each identifier can be followed by an irregular number of datapoints. the identifier is always the same string which is set by the operator (can be 'time', 'voltage' etc.)

Comment: @BoarGules I basically start with a text file that contains all measurement results. This file contains columns of data. I parse through this document and create a list for each column. within each column I have identifiers which mark when a new experiment starts. the identifier can be any string which is set by the user. the number of values is for each identifier different. columns are better for subsequent data crunching. each column contains the identifier and the subsequent values and a new column is created for the next identifier and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not write the data to a csv file, but using the csv library this is a simple step. What this does do is restructure the data from what you provided into a list of lists with each sublist being a single row of data.

```py
l = ['identifier', 1, 2, 3, 'identifier', 10, 11, 12, 13, 'identifier', 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]

def split_list(l, on):
    """Splits a list an identifier and returns a list of lists split on the
    identifier without including it."""
    splits = []
    cache = []
    for v in l:
        # Check if this is an identifier
        if v == on:
            # Add the cache to splits unless it is empty
            if cache:
                splits.append(cache)
                # Empty the cache
                cache = []
        else:
            cache.append(v)
    # Add the last cache to splits if it is not empyt
    if cache:
        splits.append(cache)
    return splits

def reshape_list(l, default=None):
    """Takes a list of lists assuming each list is a column of values and
    reshapes it to be a list of rows, if list are not all the same length None
    will be used to fill empyt spots."""
    result = []
    # Get the length of the longest list
    maxlen = max(map(len, l))
    for i in range(maxlen):
        # Create each row
        row = []
        # Extract the values from the columns
        for column in l:
            if i < len(column):
                row.append(column[i])
            else:
                row.append(default)
        result.append(row)
    return result


print(l)
t = split_list(l, 'identifier')
print(t)
r = reshape_list(t)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generate demo data:**

```
import random

random.seed(20180119) # remove to get random data between runs
id = 'identifier'

def genData():
    data = []
    for n in range(10+random.randint(1,10)):
        data.append(id)
        data.extend(random.choices(range(1,20),k=random.randint(3,12)))
    print(data)
    return data
```

Output:

```
['identifier', 18, 6, 19, 10, 12, 18, 17, 12, 
 'identifier', 10, 17, 17, 10, 15, 12, 16, 18, 19, 18, 14, 9, 
 'identifier', 6, 10, 1, 14, 4, 
 'identifier', 3, 7, 7, 4, 8, 2, 16, 8, 1, 8, 16, 6, 
 'identifier', 6, 17, 8, 8, 13, 15, 7, 9, 4, 10, 15, 
 'identifier', 17, 8, 3, 8, 2, 19, 16, 2, 5, 6, 
 'identifier', 18, 6, 18, 19, 7, 8, 14, 7, 7, 19, 
 'identifier', 13, 7, 4, 13, 
 'identifier', 15, 8, 17, 8, 1, 12, 16, 7, 5, 19, 14, 9, 
 'identifier', 18, 16, 10, 7, 16, 18, 19, 6, 15, 8, 13, 15, 
 'identifier', 15, 2, 18, 13, 7, 
 'identifier', 17, 19, 15, 4, 18, 7, 13, 17, 8, 9, 
 'identifier', 9, 17, 18, 8, 17, 17, 17, 
 'identifier', 3, 16, 15, 13, 9, 
 'identifier', 15, 12, 2, 16, 2, 5, 16, 18]
```

**Reformat:**

```
def partitionData(idToUse,dataToUse):
    lastId = None
    for (i,n) in enumerate(data):       # identify subslices of data
        if n == idToUse and not lastId:     # find first id, data before is discarded
          lastId = i
          continue

        if n == idToUse:                    # found id
          yield data[lastId:i]                  # yield sublist including idToUse
          lastId = i

    if (data[-1] != id):                    # yield rest of data
        yield data[lastId:]
```

**Write data:**

```
data = genData()
partitioned = partitionData(id, data)

import itertools
import csv
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    # like zip, but fills up shorter ones with None till longest index
    writer.writerows(itertools.zip_longest(*partitioned, fillvalue=None))
```

**result.csv:**

```
identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier;identifier
10;6;3;6;17;18;13;15;18;15;17;9;3;15
17;10;7;17;8;6;7;8;16;2;19;17;16;12
17;1;7;8;3;18;4;17;10;18;15;18;15;2
10;14;4;8;8;19;13;8;7;13;4;8;13;16
15;4;8;13;2;7;;1;16;7;18;17;9;2
12;;2;15;19;8;;12;18;;7;17;;5
16;;16;7;16;14;;16;19;;13;17;;16
18;;8;9;2;7;;7;6;;17;;;18
19;;1;4;5;7;;5;15;;8;;;
18;;8;10;6;19;;19;8;;9;;;
14;;16;15;;;;14;13;;;;;
9;;6;;;;;9;15;;;;;
```

Links:
- [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
- [csv-writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that, assuming `l` is your list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.array(l).reshape(-1,5)).set_index(0).T.to_csv('my_file.csv',index=0)
```

Comment: there is no defined answer to the questions as it is still unclear. any answer you provide will be based on your assumtion what the Q wanted, not his intent as stated in the Q

Comment: This is how I understood the question.

Comment: Got a live, thanks :) I came to the same conclusion as you (format wise) but until he states what he wants its moot to post answers "thinking" to be right - but in most cases, the Q changes trice over that way.

Comment: Question is now better specified and your solution breaks :) ■

Answer (score -1):

If your dataset is not too large, you should prepare your data first, then serialize it to csv file.

```
import csv

dataset = ['identifier', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'identifier', 10, 11, 12, 13, 'identifier', 21, 22, 23, 24]
columns = []
col = []
for datapoint in dataset:
    if datapoint == 'identifier':
        if col:
            columns.append(col)
            col = []
    else:
        col.append(datapoint)
columns.append(col)

rows_count = max((len(c) for c in columns))

with open('result.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")

    for x in range(rows_count):
        data = []
        for col in columns:
            if len(col) > x:
                data.append(col[x])
            else:
                data.append("")
        writer.writerow(data)
```